# How can I redirect page in codeigniter

Tags: redirect

I am beginning coding in codeigniter, here after the submit button the data should be insert on database and redirect to next page. For me inserting on database is successfully done but the page is not redirecting;
this is my controller - Home.php

but i am getting error as The requested URL /code/display was not found on this server.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('demo');
        //$this->load->model('Insert_data');
    }
    public function savedata()
    {

        if($this->input->post('submit'))
        {
            $data=array(
                'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
                'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                'content'=>$this->input->post('content'));

           $result=$this->Insert_data->saverecords($data);  
           if ($result)
        {
            echo "Records Saved Successfully";

            redirect(base_url().'Home/display');
        }   
        else
        {
            echo "Records not Saved Successfully";
        }
        }
    }
    public function display()
        {
            $this->load->view('display');
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('demo');
        //$this->load->model('Insert_data');
    }
    public function savedata()
    {

        if($this->input->post('submit'))
        {
            $data=array(
                'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
                'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                'content'=>$this->input->post('content'));

           $result=$this->Insert_data->saverecords($data);  
           if ($result==1)
        {
            echo "Records Saved Successfully";

            redirect('Home/display');
        }   
        else
        {
            echo "Records not Saved Successfully";
        }
        }
    }
    public function display()
        {
            $this->load->view('display');
        }

}
```